# Set HPP to run in Production not Sandbox. Getting Invalid Merchant Id error 506

Tags: global-payments-api

We have our HPP running as expected in sandbox. We then changed our MerchantId, AccountId and Secret to our 'Live' details and post to the URL

https://pay.realexpayments.com/pay

On initialization we get the 506 error Invalid Merchant ID. GlobalPay insist we are using the correct credentials.

They did share a log with us. Here is the first part showing that the environment is still set as Sandbox:

```
},
"HttpStatusCode": "200",
"environment": "Sandbox",
"level_value": 20000,
"x-gp-library-version": "--NOT-PRESENT--",
"thread_name": "https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-22",
"tags": [
  "RXP_RPOD",
  "_grokparsefailure",
  "rpod"
],
```

Is there a way to force the HPP to be in Production Environment instead of Sandbox?

Thanks
Toby

Answer (score 0):

It seems that although you've set the live credentials, you send the requests to the sandbox url.

HPP has two separate URLs for Sandbox and Production.

URL for **Production** transactions
https://pay.realexpayments.com/pay

URL for **Sandbox** transactions
https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay

You can find more details here https://developer.globalpay.com/hpp/hpp-reference

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. We are definitely posting to the https://pay.realexpayments.com/pay production endpoint....

Comment: Is that all it takes to select the environment - just posting the correct URL?